# How to overlap image or layout in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to design as attached screenshot. I need to add two images, image 1 and image 2.

[image]

Comment: You probably want to look at properties like `TranslateX` and `TranslateY` and give them negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Relative Layout for overlapping image

```
<RelativeLayout>  

<BoxView x:Name="Boxview1" BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"   
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression  
        Type=RelativeToParent,  
        Property=Width,  
        Factor=1}"  
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression  
        Type=RelativeToParent,  
        Property=Height,  
        Factor=0.3}"></BoxView>  

<BoxView BackgroundColor="Lime"  
         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression  
    Type=RelativeToView,  
    ElementName=Boxview1,  
    Property=Height,  
    Factor=0.9,  
    }"  
      RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression  
    Type=RelativeToView,  
    ElementName=Boxview1,  
    Property=Width,  
    Factor=0.5,  
    }"     
         ></BoxView>
```

if you face any issue let me know I will design it and post the code.

Comment: Boxview is overlap but I want to show image. If I want to replace boxview to image then its not fit properly.

Comment: Just replace <Boxview> with <Image> and BackgroundColor with Source.

Answer (score 4):

If you add items to a grid (same row and column), they overlap in the sequence of how they have been added to the view.

```
<Grid>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Green"/>
</Grid>
```

In this very minimalistic example, the red box will be on the bottom, with the blue and then the green box above it. You can use HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions together with Margin values to finetune the view.

This also applies if you add your elements from codebehind.

I would recommend this method especially when you are using ListViews, since RelativeLayout or AbsoluteLayout need significantly more layout time, which would be multiplied by the amount of items in your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `AbsoluteLayout` or you can use a `StackLayout` with a negative `Margin`.